# is it possible to override default angular directive with a modified one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

There's a directive in Angular named [`SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c95437f15df93e2ca735ebf015acb20be597bb6a/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts) which is supposed to keep track of selected `<option>` elements in a `<select multiple>` element on a page. At line 76, there's a host binding for `(change)` event that is bound to trigger the `onChange` routine. However, in my case I do not wish to track the selections, but instead the entire list. This directive uses `[formControl]` selector so my first thought (naturally) was to remove it from my element, but in doing so I found that the element is completely detached (naturally so) from the `FormGroup` validations.

I do want it to be part of the `FormGroup` and receive statuses based on set validations and other `FormGroup` activities, so I tried:

1. Creating a derived directive from `SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor`, but it seems Angular doesn't like that as it responds with error: '*Error: more than one built in value accessor matches form control with unspecified name*'.
2. Perhaps I could remove the `@Directive` and just apply a provider to the component that uses a `<select multiple>`? `{ provide: SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor, useClass: myClass, multi: true }` but this has had no effects as the original directive still applies.

How do you override the default directive behavior in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The control needs to be part of a `FormGroup` and the `FormGroup` must be referenced somewhere in the ancestry of `<select multiple>`. The `[formControl]` or `formControlName` property must be removed from the HTML element. This will result in directives completely removed and one of those directives applies css classes. That would leave you defining the logic for switching and applying the Angular css classes, that is, if you have defined any styles for those class names. This can be easily done in your code and a `[class]` binding could apply the classes.

The control is still associated with the `FormGroup` and will participate in all activities including any defined validations. You can use the `setValue` on the control to change its value and obviously you'd be responsible on maintaining the valid value. In my case, I had an array of objects and bunch of `option` elements generated via a loop. I also had a `[selected]` binding to my data objects, so if you do that then you can also track the selections by querying the control value for data objects that have been selected.